# Showing a selection of posts using Facebook's android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After a few days of struggling through the documentation and endless search results, I have been simply unable to find a solution to my issue, being:

I'm trying to get a public facebook page's feed through the android SDK, and filter posts from it afterwards. So far I'm already stuck on getting the feed.
Using the Graph API explorer I can easily get the feed, however, when I try to display the feed JSON items in my app, I get an error.Namely, the following:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: be.thomasmore.alloallo, PID: 2191
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONArray.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Here's my code:

```
private void getPostsFromFacebook() {

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/BulletForMyValentine/feed",
            new GraphRequest.Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {


                    JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray();
                    Log.e("testlogLog", posts.toString());
                    for(int j=0; j<posts.length();j++) {

                        textView.setText("nogeenpost");
                    }
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "message,id,created_time");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help, and my sincere apologies if I've managed to miss the answer in other posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue due to simply calling a JSONObject instead of a JSONArray

```
JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray();
```

Should have been

```
JSONArray posts = response.getJSONObject();
```

This was caused to my misreading of the JSON string.